# NetworkOnMainThreadException on Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I have one activity class and login fragment .there I have used Facebook login.Now Im having exception called.`NetworkOnMainThreadException`  .please find below the code I used.

```
 package com.maintab;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.example.tesfragement.*;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService.Session;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Login extends Fragment   {

    View view;
    ImageView loginbuttton,logoutbutton;

    Facebook fb;

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public Login(Facebook fb) {

        this.fb=fb;
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
        loginbuttton=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.loinbutton);

        thread.start();

        return view;
    }


    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            loginbuttton.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }
    });


    ImageView.OnClickListener btnClick=new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {



        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 if(fb.isSessionValid())
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"session is valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                 else{

                        fb.authorize(getActivity(), new String[]{"email"}, new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Connction Unavaliable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                 try {
                                        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(fb.request("me"));
                                        String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
                                        String lastName = json.getString("last_name");

                                        String full_name = firstName+" "+lastName;
                                        Log.d("Name", firstName+" "+lastName);

                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You already have a valid session, " + firstName + " " + lastName + ". No need to re-authorize.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }catch( Exception error ) {
                                            Toast.makeText( getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }




        }

    };
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Comment: do your Network related work into Background using AsyncTask

Comment: @SimplePlan could you please post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

do your `Network` related work into Background using `Asynchronous Task`.

For more information about Background Handler: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

and also take a look into this SO [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

You are processing Network operation  on the ui thread. Hence the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You could use `AsyncTask`, `Thread` or `volley`.

Also Fragment constructor should have no arguments.

```
public Login(Facebook fb) { // constructor has an arg
```

You could follow the facebook login for android docs @

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

There is a sample also provided in the facebook sdk i guess.

Comment: please find my edited code im getting the same Exception

Comment: @VenushkaT simple. follow the docs the link posted in my post

Comment: i have followed it but logout button didnt work on me

Comment: @VenushkaT then you din't follow it properly. You said login but now you say logout. This exception says that you are running netwrok operation on the main ui thread which is not possible. That should give you a hint to fix it

Comment: i ve seen it but to do that i have to go fragement activity.thats the main issue.i have tried it.

Comment: @VenushkaT what is the problem navigating to fragment activity??

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Your code goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Comment: i have done.please find my edited code.still im getting exception.thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Handler myHandler=new Handler();
>   Runnable runnable;

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //this is background thread.
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                myHandler.post(runnable);
            }
        }).start();
        runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //This is UI thread.U can add UI related code here
            }
        };
```

Comment: still im getting the same Exception

Comment: put this above code in method for example load() and call that method in Oncreate...

Comment: it didn't work on me.I have tried.can you edit my code.please